Next: router.push() Not Navigating Correctly in onClick Event
I have a Next and React code, and I am using router.push to navigate to other routes, which works, but sometimes router.push does not navigate to the desired path (it's possible to see that the browser URL stays the same), and instead, it just reloads the current page. This happens only when I use router.push() inside an onClick event.
Here is an example of how I am implementing router.push:
<button className='btn text-center w-75'
 onClick={() => { router.push('/path') }}>
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTerminal} className='pe-1' /> Base 
</button>

I tried use window.location.href but i has the same problem

That's probably because your button is inside a form.
By default a button inside a form has the submit type :

submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a 

you just need to specify type="button" to prevent submitting the form
<button 
  type="button"
  className='btn text-center w-75' 
  onClick={() => { router.push('/path') }}>
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTerminal} className='pe-1' /> Base 
</button>

